# Print twitter user timeline with tweepy - raise error

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm looking to print a specific user timeline and I can't seem to find a working code snippet.

From the docs:

```
API.user_timeline([id/user_id/screen_name][, since_id][, max_id][, count][, page])
```

> Returns the 20 most recent statuses posted from the authenticating
>   user or the user specified. It’s also possible to request another
>   user’s timeline via the id parameter.

My attempt:

```
user = api.get_user('WSJ')
count = 25

for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline(user, count, 2)):
    print (tweet.text)
    # print (statuts)
```

> raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
>
> tweepy.error.TweepError: Twitter error response: status code = 414

Answer (score 0):

**414** is *Request-URI Too Long*, that means the generated URI is too long to process by the twitter API server.

Maybe by reducing your parameters or your `count` value you would be able to retrieve a successful response.